# Insert data into a dynamic array in Vue / Vuex

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuex

I have the following situation: when executing a change on select I am firing a function that goes to an API and performs a search. The result of this search is a JSON. After executing the search I am trying to get some specific ids, however in my component I am not able to access them.
I'm a beginner, I apologize for mistakes and lack of standards.

Here's my code where I run the @change on page:

```
<select v-if="users.items" v-model="usuarioId" @change="getById(usuarioId)">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha um Usuário</option>
    <option v-for="user in users.items" :key="user.id" :value="user.id">{{user.nome}}</option>
</select>
```

GetById in Module:

```
import { usuarioSistemaService } from '../_services';

const state = {
all: {}
};

const actions = {
getById({ commit }, id){
  commit('getByIdRequest', id);

  usuarioSistemaService.getById(id)
    .then(
      usuarioSistemas => commit('getByIdSuccess', usuarioSistemas),
      error => commit('getByIdFailure', error)
    );
}
};

const mutations = {
getByIdRequest(state) {
  state.all = { loading: true };
},
getByIdSuccess(state, usuarioSistemas) {

  state.all = { items: usuarioSistemas };
},
getByIdFailure(state, error) {
  state.all = { error };
}
};

export const usuarioSistemas = {
namespaced: true,
state,
actions,
mutations
};
```

GetById in Service:

```
function getById(id) {
  const requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: authHeader()
  };

  return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/usuariosistema/${id}`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function handleResponse(response) {
return response.text().then(text => {
    const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
    if (!response.ok) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
            // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
            logout();
            location.reload(true);
        }

        const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    return data;
});
}
```

With the result I want to insert data (usuarioSistema.sistemaId) into this array -> systemId:

```
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            usuarioId: '',
            sistemaId: [],
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to create a javascript function in "methods:" for this, but the object always comes empty. I also tried to create something invisible on the page to feed this array, but it did not work.

Could you help me, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access store data in a component via the computed object and Vuex's mapGetters helper function:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper

Assuming that you have already performed the API call, you can do it like this in your component:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      'usuarioSistemas': 'usuarioSistemas/all'
    })
}
```

In the code, you should able to access it via this.usuarioSistemas (it is an alias for usuarioSistemas/all).